# How to show view 50% below bottom layout and 50% above bottom layout?

Tags: android, android-view, android-constraintlayout, layout-anchor

I want to display a view that is 50% should overlay anchor view and remain 50% should show above the view. if bottom layout moves up then send media icon also move up

[image]

Like the Send button in Whatsapp. How to achieve this?

Here is my XML code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/color_black"
    tools:context=".activities.MediaPreviewActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/media_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/color_white"/>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_20"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back_arrow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_10"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_back_arrow_white" />

        <com.contusfly.views.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_chat_picture"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_30"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_30"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_15"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/back_arrow"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_profile" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/delete_media"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:padding="@dimen/margin_5"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_delete_media" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/send_media"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send_media"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_layout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="@color/color_black_opacity_55"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
        
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/emoji"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_18"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_15"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_18"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/image_caption"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/image_caption"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_emoji" />


        <io.github.rockerhieu.emojicon.EmojiconEditText
            android:id="@+id/image_caption"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_10"
            android:background="@null"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sf_ui_display_regular"
            android:hint="@string/title_hint_caption"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
            android:maxLines="6"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_15"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_15"
            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/color_text_hint"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_16"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/emoji" />
        
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I wanted to display send_media image view above bottom_layout can any have an idea how to implement this?

Comment: Do you have any xml layout code to share?

Comment: @Jameido I have updated my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the button you're referring to is `send_media` you have to change it's constraints to:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/send_media"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_send_media"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_layout"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_layout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

This way both top and bottom are constrained to te top of `bottom_layout`, giving you the desired result.